Margin Annotations for Left and Right Columns
I have the following problem. I would like the \mynumber{x} from the left column to only appear in the left margin, and similarly, the \mynumber{x} from the right column to appear only in the right margin. The issue I'm currently facing is that in the right margin, the \mynumber{x} from both the left and right sides are overlapping. For example, if you look at \mynumber{126a}, you will notice that it appears bolder because the numbers from both sides are overlapping. I would like to know how to ensure that each \mynumber{} from each column appears in the correct margin. As you can see, the text is part of a bilingual project.
I will now provide the code. Thank you in advance. Best regards.
This is how it currently looks:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek, provide=*]{babel}
%\babelfont{rm}{NewComputerModern10}
% A bunch of more or less essential symbol packages and such; don't touch!
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{marginnote}
% Contador para saber en qué columna estamos
\newcounter{columnstate}

\newcommand{\mynumber}[1]{%
    \ifnum\value{columnstate}=0
    \marginnote{\footnotesize #1}[0pt] % Nota en el margen izquierdo
    \else
    \marginnote{\footnotesize #1}[0pt] % Nota en el margen derecho
    \fi
}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% Special Greek font command! (Make sure you have GFS Porson installed)
\begin{document}

    
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth} % Columna izquierda
    \section*{Texto A}
    ---\mynumber{126a}ἐπειδὴ Ἀθήναζε οἴκοθεν ἐκ Κλαζομενῶν ἀφικόμεθα, κατ᾽ ἀγορὰν ἐνετύχομεν Ἀδειμάντῳ τε καὶ Γλαύκωνι: καί μου λαβόμενος τῆς χειρὸς ὁ Ἀδείμαντος, Χαῖρ᾽, ἔφη, ὦ Κέφαλε, καὶ εἴ του δέῃ τῶν τῇδε ὧν ἡμεῖς δυνατοί, φράζε.
    
    ---ἀλλὰ μὲν δή, εἶπον ἐγώ, πάρειμί γε ἐπ᾽ αὐτὸ τοῦτο, δεησόμενος ὑμῶν.
    
    ---λέγοις ἄν, ἔφη, τὴν δέησιν.
    
    ---\mynumber{126b}καὶ ἐγὼ εἶπον: τῷ ἀδελφῷ ὑμῶν τῷ ὁμομητρίῳ τί ἦν ὄνομα; οὐ γὰρ μέμνημαι. παῖς δέ που ἦν, ὅτε τὸ πρότερον ἐπεδήμησα δεῦρο ἐκ Κλαζομενῶν: πολὺς δὲ ἤδη χρόνος ἐξ ἐκείνου. τῷ μὲν γὰρ πατρί, δοκῶ, Πυριλάμπης ὄνομα.
    
    ---πάνυ γε, ἔφη.
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % Espacio entre columnas
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth} % Columna derecha
    \section*{Texto B}
    ---\mynumber{126a}When we came from our home at Clazomenae to Athens, we met Adeimantus and Glaucon in the market-place. Adeimantus took me by the hand and said, “Welcome, Cephalus if there is anything we can do for you here, let us know.”
    
    ---“Why,” said I, “that is just why I am here, to ask a favour of you.”
    
    ---\mynumber{126b}“Tell us,” said he, “what it is.”

    ---And I said, “What was your half-brother's name? I don't remember. He was only a boy when I came here from Clazomenae before and that is now a long time ago. His father's name, I believe, was Pyrilampes.”
    
    ---“Yes,” said he.
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}


off-topic: don't load inputenc on any non-ancient system. don't load inputenc or fontenc with a unicode engine. are you sure you need xltxtra? probably you just need fontspec. hyperref should be loaded (almost) last.

you should probably consider using reledmac/reledpar (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/reledmac) which are specialised packages for this kind of work. you probably shouldn't be loading mathptmx etc. on a unicode engine, either.

You can use the first optional argument for \marginiote, or \reversemarginpar, to move the note to the left margin.  You might also try actual \twocolumn text.
